# Prove if f(z) is entire function s.t $|f(z)|\leq M|z|$ then $f(z)$ Is polynomial of degree $1$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be an entire function s.t $|f(z)|\leq M|z|$ ; $M>0$ is a constant then $f(z)$ Is polynomial of degree 1

My try $f(z)$ is entire so it can be written as a $\sum a_n z^n$

$$|\sum a_n z^n|\leq \sum |a_n||z|^n\leq M|z|$$

So $n=1$

Seems that the move $\sum |a_n||z|^n\leq M|z|$ is problematic

Comment: $f(0)=0$ and $g(z)=f(z)/z$ is bounded and entire.

Comment: As stated: at $z=0$, $|f(0)| < M \cdot 0 = 0$ gives a contradiction; so by *ex falso quodlibet* you can conclude anything you want.  Maybe it meant to say $|f(z)| \le M |z|$?

Comment: Please read @DanielSchepler's comment and restate the problem.

Comment: Sorry edited the question

Comment: Offering a bounty shall not function as a substitute for learning the basics of this chapter of your lectures...

Comment: @Did I did an it was in the first test that I did not passed

Comment: OK, then surely you remember the main results of the chapter? One of them applies **obviously** to the present setting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $z \ne 0$ let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$. Then $g$ is holomorphic on $ \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ and in $0$ the function $g$ has an isolated singularity.

From $|f(z)|\leq M|z|$,  we see that $|g(z)| \le M$ for $ z \in\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.

Riemann says: $0$ is a removable singularity of $g$. Hence there is an entire function $h$ such that $h=g$ on $ \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. By continuity we have  $|h(z)| \le M$ for all $ z \in\mathbb C $.

Now Liouville says: there is $c \in \mathbb C$ with

$$h(z)=c$$

for all $z \in \mathbb C$ . This gives

$$f(z)=cz$$

for all $z \in \mathbb C$, as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Take $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}, z \ne 0$$
and $$g(0)=f'(0)$$.

Show that $g$ is an entire function which is bounded.

Comment: $g$ is entire a fraction of 2 entire functions

Comment: Here you have to work a little more.

Comment: If the hypothesis were: for some $R$, $|f(z)| < M |z|$ whenever $|z| > R$ - then the argument would still work with $g(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z}$ for $z \ne 0$ and $g(0) = f'(0)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The integral approach you tried is indeed problematic, but let me show you one that works. The key is to look at the integrals of $|f|^2.$ From the given growth estimate we have

$$\tag 1 \int_{-\pi} ^\pi |f(re^{it})|^2\, dt \le 2\pi M^2r^2\,\,\text { for } r\ge 0.$$

On the other hand, we have $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$ just as you wrote. Note then that $f(re^{it}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n r^ne^{int}.$ So by Parseval's identity,

$$\tag 2 \int_{-\pi} ^\pi |f(re^{it})|^2\,dt = 2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2 r^{2n}.$$

Now the right side of $(2)$ grows faster than $r^2$ if $a_n\ne 0$ for some $n>1.$ By $(1),$ that can't happen. Therefore $a_n = 0$ for $n>1$ and we have  $f(z) = a_0 +a_1z.$ Because $f(0)=0,a_0=0.$ We thus conclude $f(z) = a_1z$ for all $z.$